# Custom/autogenerated item name in Forms Library

Tags: 2013, infopath, calculated-column, forms-library

I am trying to plan the auto-generated custom item name for Form library in a 2013 publishing website project.

In other words, I don't want our users to enter the name of the form every time they create an item.

We have multiple form libraries in the site. We need to use the following format:

```
<FormName> [ID: <ItemId>]

e.g. Car Insurance Request [ID: 573489]
```

where the **ItemId** is the one which SP created internally when item is created,

How to automatically set the name with desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a `retrieve data` connection, FetchID, to fetch the ID column.

Then in `submit data` connection, I used this formula:

```
xdMath:Eval(xdMath:Max(xdXDocument:GetDOM("FetchID")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataField‌​s/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:ID), 'concat("Car Insurance Request [ID: ", (d:ID or 0) + 1, "]")').
```

Hopefully it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

In your InfoPath form create a data connection with **type: Submit Data**, while creating it, system will ask for the Document Library and select the doucment library and next to that you will get a field called "File Name" with expression button, Click on the Expression button and there you can specify the formula/Expression to specify how the file names should be. Then Click Next, then finish and then Publish your Infopath form to the Library.

Then in the document library, if you create a document using this InfoPath form, then the file name for the created forms will be as per the Formula/Expression mentioned in the created data connection.

Comment: You can create a data connection that would bring the ID values from the document library. Then in the concat operation insert the ID field within the max function. Then your formula would be like `concat("Car Insurance Request [ID:',max(@ID)+1)`

Comment: To insert the ID field, click on "Insert Field Or Group" button, then select the Data connection from which you can get the ID field, then select the ID field and click ok. To insert the MAX function, click on "Insert Function" button.

Comment: On clicking of Insert Field or group button, you will get a screen with a drop down, there select your Data connection. after selecting, it will display the fields returned by the data connection, expand the fields untill you get ID*, then select ID*. then click ok.

Comment: sorry raven, I totally forgot to think about that condition, I'm happy that you found the solution and its working for you.

Comment: If you find my answer is correct\helpful, please mark it as answer because it may help others too.